# Remove the verbose description in mode line

Tags: mode-line, minor-mode

I started my Emacs Venture days ago with prelude.

but find that the mode line is verbose

> UUU:----F1  *scratch*      All of 144  (4,0)      (EL guru FlyC- company ivy EditorConfig ws Projectile super-save SP/s Pre WK (*)) 9:20AM 1.67 Mail

I want to remove the part with parenthesis `(EL guru FlyC- company ivy EditorConfig ws Projectile super-save SP/s Pre WK (*))`

How could I get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

90% of the verbosity in what you show is the list of minor modes. You can use something like [Diminish](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes) to simplify that. You should also be able to tell a minor mode that you don't care to see its "lighter" (its indicator in the mode-line).